# How long can an EU national live in the UK if they entered UK through CTA? (after Transition period)

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, ireland, brexit, common-travel-area

Will an EU national living in Ireland be subject to immigration checks when travelling from Ireland to UK after the transition period? If no, how long can they live in UK by entering UK through the CTA?

Comment: AFAIK, up to 6 months. According to http://brexitlegal.ie/the-common-travel-area-2/ EU citizens arriving via Ireland or the Crown Dependencies will be treated in the same way as those arriving as visitors through the UK border: they will have visitor status and not be able to work, study or access public funds without obtaining a visa.

Comment: @Traveller That link was very useful. It answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Traveller it should be noted, however, that regardless of the conditions governing nationals of most EU countries entering the UK from Ireland (or from anywhere else), Irish citizens will not be subject to any such restrictions.  They will continue to enjoy the right (which they have had since long before the UK joined the EC) to settle in the UK without needing to seek authorization.

Comment: @phoog Yes, of course. I wasn’t 100% sure my understanding was correct, hence a comment rather than an answer. Is it ok if I merge our two comments to post an answer?

Comment: @Traveller it's fine with me.

Comment: The proper terminology is **visitor**, which means you will not be allowed to live and work during the 6 month period. When entering from Ireland, this *may* be 3 months. Proof of entry into the UK is required (Ferry ticket etc.).